# What is the least upper bound for the size of an increasing chain in $(\omega^\omega,<^*)$?

Tags: set-theory

Since every family of functions $F\subseteq\omega^\omega$ of size $\left|F\right|<\mathfrak{b}$ is bounded, one can easily define a sequence $\{f_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ such that $\kappa=\mathfrak{b}$ and $f_\alpha<^* f_\beta$ for $\alpha<\beta<\kappa$.
What is the least upper bound for the size $\kappa$ of such sequence? Can one have $\kappa=\mathfrak{c}$?

By $f<^*g$ I mean $(\exists k)(\forall n>k)\ f(n)<g(n)$.

Comment: Under CH we have that it's $\mathfrak{c}$. But it can consistently be smaller, see van Douwen's overview in the handbook of set-theoretic topology, or the book "set theory of the continuum". The cofinality of this poset is a standard invariant, I forgot it's "letter".

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The cofinality (minimum size of a cofinal subset) of $(\omega^\omega,<^*)$ is $\mathfrak{d}$, but I cannot see how it bounds the size of a chain.

Comment: In the Cohen model this is $\omega_1$, similar to towers. This is done by an "isomorphism of names" argument. The same works for basically any proper product, such as the csp of Sacks forcing. Apart from that more or less anything can happen I guess. You can artificially add a chain of any (say regular) length and at the same time (in a product) add lots of Cohen reals. To this you can still apply the same trick for chains longer that the chain you added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim.** Assume GCH and let $\kappa > \omega_1$ be any regular uncountable cardinal. Then, after forcing with the $\kappa$-length finite support product of Cohen forcing, $\mathbb{C}_{\kappa}$, there is no chain of length greater than $\omega_1$.

This is proved via a so called "isomorphism of names" argument. Unfortunately I do not have a reference for this (maybe somebody else does), but I will outline the argument.

*Proof.* Assume $\dot f_\alpha$, $\alpha < \lambda$, are nice $\mathbb{C}_\kappa$-names for elements of $\omega^\omega$, that purportedly will form a chain and $\omega_1 < \lambda \leq \kappa$, $\lambda$ regular.

A *nice name* is, as usual, a name of the form $\bigcup_{s \in \omega^{<\omega}} \{ \check s \} \times A_{s}$, where each $A_s$ is an antichain. Thus let us write $\dot f_\alpha = \bigcup_{s \in \omega^{<\omega}} \{ \check s \} \times A_{s,\alpha}$ for each $\alpha < \lambda$. Then to each $\alpha < \lambda$, we can associate a "support" $S_\alpha \subseteq \kappa$, which is the union of all the supports of conditions in $A_{s,\alpha}$ for $s \in \omega^{<\omega}$. Then $S_\alpha$ is clearly countable and the evalutation of $\dot f_\alpha$ only depends on the restriction of the generic to $S_\alpha$. In fact, there is a Borel function $F_\alpha \colon (2^\omega)^{S_\alpha} \to \omega^\omega$ so that if $G = \langle x_i : i < \kappa \rangle$ is the generic sequence, then $\dot f_\alpha [G] = F_\alpha(\langle x_i : i \in S_\alpha \rangle)$.

Next we apply the Delta-system Lemma (using GCH), to get $X \in [\lambda]^\lambda$ and a root $R$ so that for every $\alpha \neq \beta \in X$, $S_\alpha \cap S_\beta = R$.

Now the point is, that by a pigeonhole principle (using CH and the fact that there are only continuum many Borel functions) there are $\alpha < \beta$ so that $F_\alpha$ and $F_\beta$ are the same modulo a permutation of $\kappa$ mapping $S_\alpha$ to $S_\beta$ fixing $R$ and everything else. This permutation induces an automorphism $\pi \colon \mathbb{C}_\kappa \to \mathbb{C}_\kappa$, that swaps $\dot f_\alpha$ and $\dot f_\beta$. But then, since it is forced that $\dot f_\alpha <^* \dot f_\beta$, we must also force that $\dot f_\beta <^* \dot f_\alpha$, which is impossible. This relies on the following well-known fact (I'm sure you can find it in Jech):

**Fact.** If $\varphi(x_0, \dots, x_n)$ is a formula in the language of set theory, $\tau_0, \dots, \tau_{n}$ names and $\pi$ and automrphism of the poset, then $$\Vdash \varphi(\tau_0, \dots, \tau_n) \text{ iff}\Vdash \varphi(\pi(\tau_0), \dots, \pi(\tau_n)).$$

Here we apply this fact to a formula $\varphi(x_0,x_1)$ expressing that $x_0, x_1 \in \omega^\omega$ and $x_0 <^* x_1$. $\square$

It is crucial that $<^*$ is definable without parameters (or definable over the ground model), so that its meaning is not changed by applying the automorphism. Compare this for example with a well-order of the reals in the extension. We can do everything up to the last step, where we can not apply the autormorphism argument since the well-order is not definable. (*This is exactly the proof that there is no such definable well-order that you can find in textbooks!*)

Of course this argument is very general and applies to basically any relation other than $<^*$ that is definable over the ground model.

Now how to get other values than $\omega_1$? Well first just force $\mathfrak{b}$ what ever you like to get a chain. That chain will of course be preserved in any ccc extension. Then run the argument above again replacing $\omega_1$ with the value of the continuum in that model.

This seems to only miss the case where the lub for the size of a chain could be singular. But who knows anything about singular cardinals?

Comment: Thank you very much for your in-depth answer! Just give me some time to comprehend the details of the argument. E.g., those Borel $F_\alpha$'s...

Comment: Maybe the term Borel function is a bit confusing here. The point is that up to its support $S_\alpha$, we only need a countable information (that can be coded by a real number) to determine $\dot{f}_\alpha$. Another way to see this is that $\dot{f}_\alpha$ is just a subset of $\{\check s : s \in \omega^{<\omega}\} \times \mathbb{C}_{S_\alpha}$. So it is a subset of a countable set. If we fix a bijection from $S_\alpha$ to $\omega$, we have basically a nice $\mathbb{C}_{\omega}$-name and there are only continuum many of those.

Comment: Here, I am also viewing $f_\alpha$ as $\{s \in \omega^{<\omega} : s \subseteq f_\alpha \}$, which is formally not what $f_\alpha$ is (it is a set of pairs and not a set of initial segments). But this is irrelevant. It was a typo from my side.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.Now I understand everything except the last step. We have an automorphism $\pi$ swapping the names $\dot f_\alpha$ and $\dot f_\beta$, keeping other names in the chain unchanged, and want to come to a contradiction... Is there any absolutness involved here?

Comment: Kind of. The point is that you don't want the name for $<^*$ to be changed. But this is just a definable (without any names as parameters) relation. If it wouldn't be, then the automorphism could mess it up and you would just end with $\dot f_\beta >^* \dot f_\alpha$, which didn't change anything. I will add an explanation.

Comment: Do you assume that $\mathbb{1}\Vdash\dot f_\alpha<^*\dot f_\beta$? I somehow can't see how to get it. Alternatively, let $p\in G$ be such that $p\Vdash\dot f_\alpha<^*\dot f_\beta$ for all $\alpha<\beta<\lambda$. Then there is $\alpha<\beta$  such that the support of $p$ is disjoint to $S_\alpha\cup S_\beta$, and $F_\alpha$, $F_\beta$ are the same modulo a permutation of $\kappa$ that maps $S_\alpha$ onto $S_\beta$ and fixes everything else. Then we have $\pi(p)=p$ and $\pi(p)\Vdash\pi(\dot f_\alpha)<^*\pi(\dot f_\beta)$, hence $p\Vdash\dot f_\beta<^*\dot f_\alpha$. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, I assume that the trivial condition forces that the whole sequence is a chain. The poset looks the same below any condition so this is implied if there is some condition forcing that such a chain exists. Alternatively, what you propose also works. The only thing is that the support of $p$ might have non-empty intersection with the root $R$. So $\operatorname{supp}(p) \cap (S_\alpha \cup S_\beta) \setminus R = \emptyset$.